# how set value to a dynamically created edittext

Tags: android, android-edittext

in my app i create a set of editText dynamically. how can we set values to a dynamically created editText. i create the editText and add this editText to list

the code for creating the editText is given below

```
LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(context);
    layout.setId(expRow2);
    layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    layout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    for(int i=1;i<=4;i++)
    {
        EditText editText = new EditText(context);
        editText.setHint(exp_EditTextName[i]);
        editText.setId(expRow+i);
        editText.setEms(10);
        editText.setLayoutParams(margins);
        layout.addView(editText);
        expEditTextList.add(editText);
    }
```

and i need to setValues to editText on other part of my code

```
final LinearLayout exp = new LinearLayout(context);
        exp.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        exp.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
        exp.setDescendantFocusability(LinearLayout.FOCUS_AFTER_DESCENDANTS);
        Button expAdd = new Button(context);
        expAdd.setId(123);
        expAdd.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.small_add);
        expAdd.setLayoutParams(marginLeftElement);
        exp.addView(expAdd);
        exp.addView(layout);
EditText edittext  = (EditText)expEditTextList.get(0);
edittext.setText("hai");
```

but i cant set values to the editText.

Comment: Are you able to see this edittext? And why have u added it to 2 views? layout.addView(editText);
        expEditTextList.add(editText); I think you don't need
        layout.addView(editText);

Comment: Is this how you declared `expEditTextList`: `List<EditText> expEditTextList = new ArrayList<EditText>();`?

Comment: @ cplain ya sure i declared it..

Comment: @ shreya  ya i can see the editText i added these editText into a linear layout. and this layout is added into my child view.

Comment: Then it should be layout.addView(editText);
        expEditTextList.add(layout);

Comment: why we add layout to a expEditTextList

Comment: You told that ". and this layout is added into my child view."

Comment: ok... then the layout must be keep in a list.
 am i right??

Comment: and how i setText into editText..??

Comment: I think it would be better to skip layout part and add edittext directly to list if the listview row is going to contain only edittext. Then no layout needed

Comment: acutally i need to create editText dynamicaly on button click. so i add editText to a linear layout which has a horizontal orientation. and i add the layout to the child view

Comment: i use layout.getchildAt() method?

Answer (score 0):

try like this..

```
final EditText text1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.text1);
final EditText text2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.text2);
final EditText text3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.text3);

text2.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        text3.setText(text1.getText().toString() + text2.getText().toString());
    };
});
```

for more information try the link

[set text on dynamically created edittext in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9339315/set-text-on-dynamically-created-edittext-in-android)

Comment: i am sorry frnd.. its not an answer that i expect

Comment: @user1882058 did you check the link